# Why do we need to have absolute values of V(number of Vertices) and E(Number of Edges) in upper bound of various Graph algorithms

Tags: css, algorithm, graph

I have been reading through the Graph Algorithms recently and saw the notation for various upper bounds of graph algorithms is of the form O(|V| + |E|). especially in DFS/BFS search algorithms where linear time is achieved with above upper bound.

I have seen both the notations interchangeably used, i.e. O(V+E) as well. as far as I understand "|" bar notation is used for absolute values in math world. if V = # of vertices and E = # of Edges, how can they be negative numbers, such that we have need to get the  absolute values before computing the linear function. Please help.

Comment: Absolute value in this notation is the size of the set. V is a set. |V| is the size of it. The complexity is `O(|V| + |E|)`, since it depends on the size of the set. Writing `O(V+E)` is basically a lazy (which I also sin at) and unformal way to write `O(|V| + |E|)`

Comment: @amit, if I understand correctly, the right way of expressing the upper bound is with the correct set size notation. Thanks for the sharing, I won't be lazy now on :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

|X| refers to the cardinality (size) of X when X is a set.

O(V+E) is *technically* incorrect, assuming that V and E refer to sets of vertices and edges. This is because the value inside O( ) should be quantitative, rather than abstract sets of objects that have an ambiguous operator applied to them. |V| + |E| is well-defined to be one number plus another, whereas V + E could mean a lot of things.

However, in **informal scenarios** (e.g. conversing over the internet and in person), many people (including me) still say O(V+E), because the cardinality of the sets is implied. I like to type fast and adding in 4 pipe characters just to be technically correct is unnecessary.

But if you need to be technically correct, i.e. you're in a formal environment, or e.g. you're writing your computer science dissertation, it's best to go with O(|V|+|E|).

Comment: I'm tempted to downvote this because it seems to tacitly endorse sloppiness, which is something awful in a formal environment; anyone makes mistakes, but it can become really difficult to understand things that contain both mistakes and willful sloppiness.

Comment: @G.Bach You make a good point. I have edited my answer to consider differences between formal and informal scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the vertical bars `||` denote the cardinality or number of elements of a set (i.e. `|E|` represents the count of elements in the set `E`).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality

Comment: Thats true, as amit in another comment also suggested, I was mixing it up with notation of absolute values see this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value